# Unable to send a message to specific channel in Slack with Hubot - SlackRTMError: no channel id

Tags: javascript, slack, hubot

Simple script but it's not working properly.. I'm trying to send a message to a specific channel determined by the user's input.

Code:

```
module.exports = function(robot) {

    robot.respond(/in (.*) say (.*)/i, function(msg) {

        var channel = msg.match[1];
        var sentence = msg.match[2];

        robot.send(channel, sentence);
    });
}
```

When I run it, hubot throws the following error:

> 2016-09-01T18:46:36.836661+00:00 app[web.1]: **Unhandled rejection
>   SlackRTMError: no channel id**
>
> 2016-09-01T18:46:36.836677+00:00 app[web.1]:   at
>   RTMClient.handleMessageAck [as _handleMessageAck]
>   (/app/node_modules/hubot-slack/node_modules/@slack/client/lib/clients/rtm/client.js:497:40)
>   2016-09-01T18:46:36.836679+00:00 app[web.1]:   at
>   RTMClient._handleWsMessageViaEventHandler
>   (/app/node_modules/hubot-slack/node_modules/@slack/client/lib/clients/rtm/client.js:460:12)
>   2016-09-01T18:46:36.836680+00:00 app[web.1]:   at
>   RTMClient.handleWsMessage
>   (/app/node_modules/hubot-slack/node_modules/@slack/client/lib/clients/rtm/client.js:420:10)
>   2016-09-01T18:46:36.836683+00:00 app[web.1]:   at WebSocket.emit
>   (events.js:98:17) 2016-09-01T18:46:36.836684+00:00 app[web.1]:   at
>   Receiver.ontext
>   (/app/node_modules/hubot-slack/node_modules/@slack/client/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:841:10)
>   2016-09-01T18:46:36.836685+00:00 app[web.1]:   at
>   /app/node_modules/hubot-slack/node_modules/@slack/client/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:536:18
>   2016-09-01T18:46:36.836686+00:00 app[web.1]:   at
>   /app/node_modules/hubot-slack/node_modules/@slack/client/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:368:7
>   2016-09-01T18:46:36.836687+00:00 app[web.1]:   at
>   /app/node_modules/hubot-slack/node_modules/@slack/client/node_modules/ws/lib/PerMessageDeflate.js:249:5
>   2016-09-01T18:46:36.836687+00:00 app[web.1]:   at afterWrite
>   (_stream_writable.js:278:3) 2016-09-01T18:46:36.836688+00:00
>   app[web.1]:   at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:270:7)
>   2016-09-01T18:46:36.836689+00:00 app[web.1]:   at
>   WritableState.onwrite (_stream_writable.js:97:5)
>   2016-09-01T18:46:36.836689+00:00 app[web.1]:   at afterTransform
>   (_stream_transform.js:99:5) 2016-09-01T18:46:36.836690+00:00
>   app[web.1]:   at TransformState.afterTransform
>   (_stream_transform.js:74:12) 2016-09-01T18:46:36.836691+00:00
>   app[web.1]:   at Zlib.callback (zlib.js:456:5)
>   2016-09-01T18:46:36.836691+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2016-09-01T18:46:36.836681+00:00 app[web.1]:   at WebSocket.wrapper
>   (/app/node_modules/hubot-slack/node_modules/@slack/client/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4762:19)

Any ideas why it is not working? I've used #general and general to test the functionality of it but it hasn't worked

Comment: Suggests `channel` is undefined, have you tried logging it to make sure it's what you expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks! I found the id using msg.envelope.channel. I didn't know where it was stored so I couldn't address it.

```
for(x in msg.envelope) {
    console.log(x + " : " + msg.envelope[x]);
}
```

That was the best way to check the variables of the msg object. Plus I had to send it using **msg.messageRoom(roomID, msg)** instead of robot.send.

Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

In Slack API, channels are not their names, but instead some form of IDs. You can tell by an ID that it is channel ID when its first letter is "C", like in `C024BE91L`.

I believe what you need is to get channel ID by its name. To do that, use [`channels.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.list) method to fetch all the channels, and then `Array#find` to find a proper channel by its name:

```
bot.api.channels.list((error, response) => {
  const targetChannel = response.data.find(channel => channel.name === message.match[1]);

  robot.send(targetChannel.id, sentence);
});
```

Just optimize it to not call this API every time your bot receives a message, and it should work.

PS You can even see discussion of similar problem [in this issue on Github](https://github.com/howdyai/botkit/issues/7).

Comment: In this snippet, is `bot` the same as the `robot` object?

Comment: Just as I cannot be sure where `robot` comes from, I cannot be sure if `bot` and `robot` are the same. I'm using the term that's widely used in official docs. But they should be the same.